# Double Quotes in ASCII

Tags: ascii

What is the ASCII number for the double quote? (")

Also, is there a link to a list anywhere?

Finally, how do you enter it in the C family (esp. C#)

Comment: As for your last question, "\"" usually does the trick.

Comment: Pascal, how do you enter it in a string? vara + Char34 + varb + "some string";

Comment: const char DblQuote = @'"'; string s = "hello " + DblQuote + "\" world"; That is in C#.

Comment: I suppose this is deemed so elemental that it's hard to take the question seriously. ASCII tables aren't particularly hard to find, anyway which answers your two original questions already without too much effort. Generally it's frowned upon if people don't apply their Google-Fu before asking a question.

Comment: actually needs to be `const char DblQuote = '"';`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ASCII code for the quotation mark is 34.

There are plenty of [ASCII tables](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table) on the web. Note that some describe the standard 7-bit ASCII code, while others describe various 8-bit extensions that are super-sets of ASCII.

To put quotation marks in a string, you escape it using a backslash:

```
string msg = "Let's just call it a \"duck\" and be done with it.";
```

To put a quotation mark in a character literal, you don't need to escape it:

```
char quotationMark = '"';
```

Note: Strings and characters in C# are not ASCII, they are Unicode. As Unicode is a superset of ASCII the codes are still usable though. You would need a Unicode character table to look up some characters, but an ASCII table works fine for the most common characters.

Comment: how do you enter it like this? vara + Char34 + varb + "some string";

Comment: @Arlen: You put it in a string: vara + "\"" + varb + "some string". (You could use a character literal also, but that would be pointless as it will be converted to a string before concatenation anyway.)

Comment: @Guffa: why does the escape character/backslash *not* matter? (`'"'` and `'\"'` are the same, why?)

Answer (score 9):

It's 34. And you can find a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters).

Comment: const char DblQuote = @'"'; 
string s = "hello " + DblQuote + "\" world"; 

That is in C#

Comment: Guffa: You put it in a string: vara + "\"" + varb + "some string". (You could use a character literal also, but that would be pointless as it will be converted to a string before concatenation anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

yes, the answer the 34

In order to find the ascii value for special character and other alpha character I'm writing here small vbscript. In a note pad, write the below script save as abc.vbs(any name with extention .vbs) double click on the file to execute and you can see double quotes for 34.

```
For i=0 to 150

msgbox i&"="&char(i)

next
```

Answer (score 1):

you are never going to need only 1 quote, right?
so I declare a CHAR variable i.e

```
char DoubleQuote;
```

then drop in a double quote

```
Convert.ToChar(34);
```

so use the variable `DoubleQuote` where you need it

works in SQL to generate dynamic SQL but there you need

```
DECLARE @SingleQuote CHAR(1)
and
SET @SingleQuote=CHAR(39)
```