# Choose Randbetween function giving me a #NAME? error in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am using this formula in excel

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,6),”Item1″,“Item2”,“Item3”,“Item4”,“Item5”,“Item6”)
```

It's supposed to pick one of those values at **random and return it** in the cell, but I just get #NAME?.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `#NAME?` error signifies that something needs to be corrected in the syntax, so when you see the error in your formula, think of the syntax.

I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. But if you have copy-pasted the code into your Excel from a blogpost or somwhere else, maybe the double quotes characters are not the chars that Excel expect.

Try the following code instead, which has the standard double quotes.

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,6),"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5","Item6")
```

[Further info here](https://exceljet.net/formula/randomly-assign-data-to-groups)

---

**Whay does this happen?** That comes from how computers work with characters (It's called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). Maybe it's a very deep topic for the scope of this post. But, basically most programming languages accept only one type of character, while the platform (your *Operating System*) usually allows you a variety of representations for the same symbol (but different ASCII code), and that are thought for different contexts. In short, the double quotes look similar but the ASCII code are different:

```
" this char is accepted by Excel for enclosing values (open and close)


“ this char is not accepted by Excel for enclosing values (open)
” this char is not accepted by Excel for enclosing values (close)
```

For technical reference on this you can [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134779/double-quotes-in-ascii)

Comment: Well, that worked apparently. But I'm confused, how are there two double quotes characters?

Comment: That comes from how computers work with characters. Maybe it's a very deep topic for the scope of this post. But, basically most programming languages accept only one type of character, while the platform usually provides a variety of representations for the same symbol, and that are thought for different contexts. For technical reference on this you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134779/double-quotes-in-ascii